# Send HTTP Unauthorized (401) from ChannelInterceptorAdapter with Spring

Tags: http, spring-websocket

I'm trying to figure out how to respond with a 401 Status within a ChannelInterceptorAdapter in case a WebSocket connect is unauthorised.

```
@Component
public class ConnectInterceptor extends ChannelInterceptorAdapter {

final AuthorizationService mAuthService;

@Autowired
public ConnectInterceptor(final AuthorizationService authService) {
    mAuthService = authService;
}

@Override
public Message<?> preSend(final Message<?> message, final MessageChannel channel) {
    final StompHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(message);
    if (StompCommand.CONNECT.equals(headerAccessor.getCommand())) {

        final String authValue = (String)headerAccessor.getHeader("Authorization");

        ApiPrincipal principal;
        try {
            principal = mAuthService.authorize(authValue);
        } catch (final UnauthorizedException e) {

            //response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, "AdditionalInformationIfAvailable")??               
        }

        headerAccessor.setUser(principal);
    }
    return message;
}

}
```

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm running into similar issues.